# InetAddress getAllByName does not manage order of return IP Addresses as mentioned in host entry

Tags: java, linux, networking, inetaddress

My Host entry as follow :

```
    10.106.1.188 myhost
    192.168.0.156 myhost
    192.168.0.160 myhost
    192.168.0.150 myhost
    10.106.1.121 myhost
    10.106.1.110 myhost
```

I use following code for get all IP Address from host entry

```
InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName("myhost");
    for( InetAddress address : addresses) {
        System.out.println(address);
    }
```

Problem is above code does not manage Ip Address order.

When Running above program on Windows 7 it works fine but on linux machine it does not manage order

Comment: What is `getIpAddressByHostName()`? No such method in the JDK.

Comment: sorry, its InetAddress.getAllByName(hostName), see edited question
Thanks for correction

Comment: There's nothing in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName(java.lang.String)) about a specific order.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Use Comparator which should sort the IP address for you. other wise you will get platform dependent results. Here is one example http://thilosdevblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/sorting-ip-addresses-in-java/
This example keeps Ordering intact.

Comment: But I want all IP Address in order as in host entry

Answer (score 1):

The order of addresses returned by [java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAllByName-java.lang.String-) is undefined. If it works on one platform for you then it's just a happy accident.

Remember that the results may not always come from a hosts file, but from the result of a DNS lookup (where the order is also undefined).

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem on *Windows* machine with multiple interfaces (IP addresses). What I noticed that `inetAddress.getAllByName()` function returns list of IPs accordingly their interface ID i.e. the topmost IP in the list will be the IP of the interface with highest ID (OS specific internal list). You could lookup the list of interfaces via command in *Windows* cmd line: `route print`

```
Interface List
  7...02 00 xx xx xx xx ......Microsoft KM-TEST Loopback Adapter
  3...fc aa xx xx xx xx ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-V
  8...02 01 xx xx xx xx ......SAMSUNG Mobile USB Remote NDIS Network Device
  4...00 e0 xx xx xx xx ......Realtek PCI GBE Family Controller
   .   .   .   .   .
  9...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 32...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
```

Thus in this example, first IP in the list of `getAllByName()` call will be IP of the interface 8 (*SAMSUNG Mobile USB Remote...*).